# How To Display column with default values in xamgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am displaying columns from database and it's displaying from `DB using its Key`. But I need to show `one column as a default value` 1. That column is not in DB. I have created `BalName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this thing by assigning Default value into your Sql or mysql queries like

```
select -------, 1 as 'defaultvalue' ---------------
```

and use a column into your grid and bind that grid column with `defaultvalue`.
Binding will be same as you are using for other fields as well.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: Can U please Explain It Breifly please @rahul

Comment: you may directly use a default value into your sql or mysql query means hard code values.in that problem you have to use a hard code value like i mentioned and bind that field with your grid column.